# How would I find the maximum error of a reconstructed curve?

Tags: matlab, plot, curve-fitting

I'm working on something reconstructs a curve from the curvature at a few specific points, and the reconstruction seems to work quite well. [image: The graph is here] The blue line being the original curve and the red dashed line being the reconstruction.

I was wondering, **how would I go about finding the maximum error of my reconstruction?**
My thinking would be solving a max-min problem, where I'm finding the maximum of the minimum (perpendiular) distance from each point on the curve, but this is really inefficient. From this, I'm also unsure what to use to calculate the percentage error - is it the difference in `y`'s, or maybe the difference in arc length up to that point?

Comment: Why not using `max(y1-y2)` (or rather of the absolute -- `abs` -- error)?. If your curves are not equally sampled, interpolate them first (`interp1`)

Comment: "but this is really inefficient" How so? It seems like a fairly simple computation, no? // "what to use to calculate the percentage error" How do you define the percentage error? That's the error as a percentage of what?

Comment: I guess I was thinking of needing to do a lot of iterations. What I'm actually resorting to, but let me know if you think this isn't a great way, is finding the perpendicular distance from point to point (like max said) and computing the RMS over the whole curve. For a percentage I'm then dividing by arc length.